# UnityEngine.Object instances have no name property in test

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine

Assigning names to my objects (like the ones returned from the global `Instantiate` method) is breaking my tests. Anyone have any ideas for how to get around such things in test?

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnityEngine;

[TestFixture()]
public class BoardSpec{
    [Test()]
    public void NamePropertyWorks(){
        var obj = new UnityEngine.Object();
        obj.name = "object name";
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving: `System.MissingMethodException : Cannot find the requested method.`
The first line of the stack trace gives: `at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Object:set_name (string)`

Unity 5.2.0f3, running tests in MonoDevelop-Unity 4.0.1 on osx

_____update 9/20______
It sounds like creating new `Object`s is not recommended, but this code fails with the same error:

```
    [Test()]
    public void ScriptableObjectNamePropertyWorks(){
        var obj = new ScriptableObject();
        obj.name = "object name";
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate a new object into the scene?

Comment: no in my actual use case I wrap the global `Instantiate` in an object which I swap out in test to just return a `UnityEngine.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Never create nor inherit directly form `UnityEngine.Object`, use [`ScriptableObject`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) instead

Doing something like `(new UnityEngine.Object()).name = "text"` will always throw a `null reference` exception, as I'll explain below. From there to the `System.MissingMethodException` you are getting, it depends on the inner workings of NUnit.

Unity uses `UnityEngine.Object` in a very special way, keeping track of objects, and considering some "not alive" despite existing. The `Equals` comparison for `UnityEngine.Object` is overriden to reflect this, and an existing Object might equal null:

```
    // Both Mesh and MyObject inherit directly from UnityEngine.Object
    Object plainObject = new UnityEngine.Object();
    Mesh meshObject = new UnityEngine.Mesh();
    MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber(123456f);

    // using the overriden Unity.Object.Equals()
    print(plainObject != null); // false
    print(meshObject != null); // true
    print(myNumber != null); // false

    // With traditional null checking, everything exists of course, as we just created them
    print(plainObject as System.Object != null); // true
    print(meshObject as System.Object != null); // true
    print(myNumber as System.Object != null); // true

    print(myNumber.number); // prints 123456, the object is there and perfectly operational
    print(myNumber.name); // the program ends with a null reference exception thrown by the name set accessor, because myNumber is not "alive"
```

Every native Unity class that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` makes any needed internal call to register the object as "alive", but this is **not** done in the base class itself. Basically, any attempt to create a vanilla Object, or something directly inherited from it, will be considered stillborn by the engine, and you won't get it to work as usual. If you need to create or inherit from Objects, use [`ScriptableObject`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) instead, that has an explicitly special behaviour in the inner workings.

Comment: Thanks for this help, @Emilio! I am now returning a `ScriptableObject`, but getting the same error :/. I've added more context in the question. If this looks like question drift, I can ask a different question rather than adding onto this one like I just did.

Comment: @Charlie btw, you should use ScriptableObject.CreateInstance() to create ScriptableObjects, but that is not the problem